# Why does my button appear outside the containing div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/samholder/T4XY4/) which shows my issue. You may need to make the 'result' quadrant wider to show the issue.

I have a couple of columns in my bootstrap layout but I can't seem to get my button to layout inside the parent div, it always seems to overlap it:

[image: Why the overlap?]

At first I thought it was due to the padding of the columns in bootstrap but I have removed that and the problem persists. I'm obviously missing something fundamental about how this is supposed to work, so any pointers to some help with css might not go amiss either.

apparently I have to link to some code to include a link to a fiddle so here is some:

My html is:

```
 <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 nopadding">
     <div class="definition-pallette">
          <div class="row nopadding">
                <div class="col nopadding"><button data-bind="click: showStepModal">+ Step</button></div>
          </div>
     </div>
  </div>
```

and the additional css on top of the bootstrap default is:

```
.nopadding {
   padding-left: 0 !important;
   padding-right: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a few things going on here. The main issue is you are using a lot of divs with a class of 'col' inside your 'row' divs. To get them to start behaving you need to define what size the col is. This fixes most of your problems. So for example, where you have this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Change that to something like

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xs-12">Some content</div>
</div>
```

And it starts behaving.

I also got rid of your `.nopadding` class as you don't need that.

Here is an updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/T4XY4/1/ - it fixes most of the things in the right panel, but I'll leave the rest to you. You may want to choose which classes you actually want inside your 'row' divs, I just chucked in `xs-12` for simplicity.

**Edit**

The Bootstrap docs confirms that if you are nesting columns you need proper `col-*` classes - http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting

Comment: Thanks Rob, that's a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Its caused by bootstraps margins in the row class adding margin:0; to your no padding class will fix this but might cause layout issues in other places or on mobile devices.

```
.row {
     margin-right: -15px;
     margin-left: -15px;
}
```